# How to close an Azure Service Bus session with Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: java, session, spring-cloud-stream, servicebus

How can we close (dispose) an Azure Service Bus session through Spring Cloud Stream when all the expected messages have been received ?
I can't see a bean or a method to call.

My producer works fine, I add a 'sessionID' header in the message:

```
public class MessagesProducer {
  private Sinks.Many<Message<String>> many;

  public void doSend() {
    Message<String> msg = MessageBuilder //
      .withPayload("" + messageId) //
      .setHeader(ServiceBusMessageHeaders.SESSION_ID, sessionId) //
      .build();
    many.emitNext(msg, (signalType, emitResult) -> {
      log.error("Fail #{}: EmitFailureHandler received a '{}' signal: {}", failedNb, signalType, emitResult);
      return true;
        });
  }
}
```

My consumer also works fine:

```
public class MessagesConsumers {
  @Bean
  public Consumer<Message<String>> consumerFromSubscription2() {
    return message -> {
      final MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
      final Object sessionID = headers.get(ServiceBusMessageHeaders.SESSION_ID);
      log.info("Message #{} received from subscription with session '{}'", message.getPayload(), sessionID);
    };
  }
}
```

But I can't see how to dispose the session ID in the consumer.

There is no documentation / sample in the Azure documentation to dispose a session through Spring Cloud Stream